# Retrieve all sales for customer

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to get list of customers and then group sales per customer, the code below works, but not how I want it to.

I'm really after each customer to display once then all sales per customer.

```
SELECT i.item, i.Qty, c.NAME, c.address, s.OrderNo, s.OrderDate
FROM CUSTOMERS c
LEFT JOIN Sales s
ON c.name = s.cust
LEFT JOIN Items i
on i.OrderNo = s.OrderNo
WHERE s.Cust IS not NULL
```

Comment: What does your schema look like? And when you say "it works, but not how I want it to", what output does it give, versus what output do you want? Providing examples goes a long way.

Answer (score 0):

--SubQuery the summed value by customer from the sales table then join to that.
SELECT i.item, i.Qty, c.NAME, c.address, s.OrderNo, s.OrderDate, s.SUM_CUSTOMER_SALES_VALUE
FROM CUSTOMERS c
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT Cust, SUM(CUSTOMER_SALES_VALUE) AS SUM_CUSTOMER_SALES_VALUE FROM Sales GROUP BY Cust ) s
ON c.name = s.cust
LEFT JOIN Items i
on i.OrderNo = s.OrderNo
WHERE s.Cust IS not NULL